# After Effects: How to animate letters to random position

Tags: after-effects

Is it possible to animate letters to random position in After Effects? Yes I can do it manualy letter by letter but I want to achieve effect like on animation below for any input text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write a complicated expression which will allow you to do that. If you deal with short words like those though, I would recommend you duplicate the text layer and mask out one letter for each layer. You can then animate each layer in position and scale so that the letters move into place

Answer (score 0):

How about **Text->Animate->Position** and then **Add->Selector->Wiggly**? If you then set that Position to non-zero value, letters will skip around randomly over time and Selector properties will give you some control over the process.